# Can I set a default server in PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin

I have a phpMyAdmin deployment that connects to a MySQL server within the same docker swarm. Can I set it up to use a "default" server so I don't have to type in a docker service name to log into phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phpMyAdmin Docker container allows you to define a server with a command such as

> docker run --name myadmin -d -e PMA_HOST=dbhost -p 8080:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin

Further, you can [add your own custom configuration](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker#adding-custom-configuration) which would allow you to define `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']` (as well as other directives) in your configuration file.